# Getting part of a URL path via Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to get part of a path in URL via Angular.js and i found solution:
http://mywebsite.com/one/HEREiWANT/three

first i do this:

```
app.config(function($locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

then i define my controller like this:

```
app.controller("mainCtrl", function ($scope,$location) {
//...
}
```

then with this method i can get what i want and it works!:

```
$scope.getURLPart = function () {
    return pId = $location.path().split("/")[3]||"Unknown";
};
```

But this has a huge problem, right now after this changes, all of my linkes in my website doesn't work. When i click on a link, address in browsers address bar changes but i stay at the same page and redirection process doesn't happen. Why? How i can achieve what i want without with this problem?

Comment: AngularJS is a framework, it's not just set of methods. So if you are building web-app, it's good to use router. (For example ui-router)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your state if your using state and yor passing params to your state then you can use

> $stateparams to get the params
>
> $stae.go("particular state name") to route to states